# Using the Apachi Poi Package in Command line programming

Tags: java, environment-variables, apache-poi

I have been recently working on a Java project which has made me need the Apachi Poi package to be able to work with Excel files. I have already downloaded the Apachi Poi software, and unzipped it, but I am not sure where to go from here.
I have tried:

- Adding select Apachi Poi .jar files to the Enviornment variable Path, using this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi/apache_poi_environment.htm
- Trying to flat out use it with an `import` statement
- I have Apache Poi 3.11 installed
- Directory for Apachi Poi: `C:\Users\Mark\Downloads\poi-bin-3.11-20141221`
   Using the binary version
- Directory for my coding project: `C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Java\Metro`

Just to be clear, I am not using a SDK, but rather coding in a text file and using the command line to run the programs.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: it should be as simple as listing all (if more than 1) of POIs jar files in the classpath of javac when compiling and java when executing. I'm not sure if POI itself has further dependencies, but this is a good place to start. i would create a lib directory under Metro and copy the jar files into there.

Comment: @SlipperySeal Can you elaborate? I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: you'll need to do some research on the basics of java programming, jar files and dependencies (the "classpath"). maybe look at some tutorials which include external jar files.

Comment: @SlipperySeal Can you suggest some? The interwebs are full of not helpful things, and it is difficult to pick out the good ones. Thanks!

Comment: this should get you started:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)